# Problem connecting localdb to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I worked with Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2017 without problems. Updated to Visual Studio 2019 and there was a problem connecting to the local server.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "A network or specific instance error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server could not be found or is unavailable. Make sure the instance name is correct and that remote connections are allowed on SQL Server. (Provider : SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - A Local Database Runtime error occurred. An unexpected error occurred while calling the LocalDB instance API method. For more information about the error, see the Windows Application Event Log.`

This error is knocked out upon first access to the database.

PS: Entity Framework is installed

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB. I installed the SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB, but this did not work. It's test project.

My context class:

```
public class ContextDb : DbContext
{
     public ContextDb() : base("name=ContextDb") 
     {
     }

     public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

My connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContextDb" 
         connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=TestDb.ContextDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you able to connect with TestDb database using ssms? Go to services and make sure SQL server services are running. Try using Server Explorer => Data Connections => Add Connection in Visual Studio.